# Bring linear map to a new basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I have a linear map:

$$A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    -1   & 3 & -1 \\
    -3 & 5  & -1\\
    -3 & 3  & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Find the basis and its matrix upon transition to which the linear map A becomes the diagonal matrix.

So i understand that i need to use formula of matrix of the transformation $TAT^{-1}$, but what kind of calculations need to be done then?

I calculated eigenvalues and eigenvectors and i got that:
$\lambda_{1} = 4, \lambda_{2} = 1$

eigenvectors for $\lambda_{2} = 1$:
$x_{2}=x_{3}, x_{1} = -0.4x_{3}$

Comment: Do you know how to find the matrix representation of a linear map with respect to a specific basis?

Comment: Do you know how to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: @Azif00 i edited question

Comment: @J.W.Tanner i edited question

Comment: You can diagonalize a matrix by finding its eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but you gave only one eigenvector, and it's not right, because it doesn't satisfy $A\vec x=\lambda_2\vec x$

Comment: How did you end up with only two eigenvalues for a $3\times3$ matrix? The trace of $A$ is $5$, so neither of them can be a repeated eigenvalue, either.

Answer (score 1):

You can diagonalize a matrix by finding its eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Set $\det 
\begin{vmatrix}
    -1-\lambda   & 3 & -1 \\
    -3 & 5-\lambda  & -1\\
    -3 & 3  & 1-\lambda
\end{vmatrix}=0.$

I.e., $-\lambda^3+5\lambda^2-8\lambda+4=(\lambda-2)^2(\lambda-1)=0$.

For $\lambda=2$, solutions to  $
\begin{pmatrix}
    -3   & 3 & -1 \\
    -3 & 3  & -1\\
    -3 & 3  & -1
\end{pmatrix}v=0$

are linear combinations of $\pmatrix{1\\0\\-3}$ and $\pmatrix{0\\1\\3}$.

For $\lambda=1$, solutions to  $ \begin{pmatrix}
    -2   & 3 & -1 \\
    -3 & 4  & -1\\
    -3 & 3  & 0
\end{pmatrix}v=0$ are multiples of $\pmatrix{1\\1\\1}.$

In a basis of eigenvectors, the matrix is $D=\pmatrix{2&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&1}$.

The matrix to transition coordinates from eigenvectors to standard basis has eigenvectors as columns:  $T=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1\\0&1&1\\-3&3&1\end{pmatrix}$.

You can verify that $A=TDT^{-1}$ or $D=T^{-1}AT$  .